# How to get relative path in XPath?

Tags: xpath, firepath

I am facing an issue with FirePath
I am getting

```
html/body/center/center[3]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input
```

from the XPath of the FirePath. This is an absolute path.
But I need a relative path.
How to get it?

Comment: Please add the html code snippet for which you are getting this absolute xpath.

Answer (score 3):

Better way is to write your own custom relative xpath.

There is an alternate way to get the relative xpath with help of the FirePath tool also. To get relative XPATH: Click on the drop down menu on the Firepath button and Unselect ‘Generate absolute XPath’.[image: As shown below:]

Then you should be getting relative XPATH (remove the "." from generated XPATH) as shown below:
[image]